# Meta Title doesn't appear in view page source but its does in inspect

Tags: angular, dynamic, server-side-rendering, meta-tags, angular-universal

I was trying to make my meta tags dynamic with installing angular universal.
After a lot of issues I had to solve to add angular universal to my project.
and now its working perfectly. I run the project using npm run dev:ssr tag.
hopefully to see my dynamic meta tags works. but unfortunately its didn't work and there is no any error message.

After a lot of search about this issue I just think the problem could be because of code cant work with angular universal. but the question is how to know what works and what doesn't with angular universal?

Angular and Angular universal Versions: 14

*server.ts*

```
import 'zone.js/node';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';

import 'localstorage-polyfill';
const MockBrowser = require('mock-browser').mocks.MockBrowser;
const mock = new MockBrowser();
global['localStorage'] = localStorage;
global['document'] = mock.getDocument();
global['window'] = mock.getWindow();
// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/PTechs/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
      bootstrap: AppServerModule,
      inlineCriticalCss: false,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

I created a new project and installed angular universal and set meta tags its work without any issues. then I just compared between the two projects all the files which related to angular universal to make sure there is no difference.

Please if you need more informations just tell me.

Comment: You need to check the console where the `dev:ssr` or `start:ssr` command is run for errors. There's almost certainly an error being shown there. If you fixed that, your problem should be solved

Comment: @Pieterjan I got this warning

`./node_modules/mock-browser/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils.js:235:21-40 - Warning: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by my self it was so stupid problem and I didn't understand exactly why.
there was a conflict with a random module in my project when I removed the implementation of the module it Solved!

and that's why all people say angular universal is a garbage :)

Comment: What was this random module please ?

Comment: It was `ExtrasModule` I hope its the same for you

Answer (score 1):

I think angular universal is garbage. I searched all the internet , everyone complains about the same problem but there is no solution to it.
What help is to prerender a website for SEO purposes if you can't add meta tags.

I would ban every article that says you can do seo with angular.
It's a disaster

I spent so much time on this and started the project in angular because it's the language i like the most and i'm proficient with it just to learn in the end it doesn't work.

I installed angular ssr from the creation of the project.. i was seeing in the element inspector the meta tags. But surprise.. google was not indexing. When i went deeper into this issue i found out my page source when viewed is misses the meta tags.

Tried with both scully io and angular universal. Both have issues.
The first one has routing issues the second one has metadata issues.

Comment: Ye it is garbage :)
I know what the problem now but I don't know how to solve it
I have to edit the whole code to make it work ,
server-side applications can’t reference browser-only global objects such as window, document, navigator, or location.
I dont know what to do its sucks

Comment: Fortunately google can read javascript. I generated a sitemap.xml after i used universal prerender. Despite meta tags are not present in the prerendered html , google catched up the added meta tags from javacript. It indexed all my website, and on some keywords i am first in position. I still think universal is kinda garbage.. but angular is the only thing i worked with for the past 4 years so for me it was the way to go. With the prerendered site.. it loads super fast. I am pleased with the result despite a bit of inconsitency with the meta tags.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand 
do you know how to fix it? if yes please tell me

Answer (score 0):

try to add this service on your contructor and import it :

private titleService: Title,

then add your title :

this.titleService.setTitle("Besoin d'une assurance");

Comment: I already did it but the problem is its  doesn't appear in view page source  just in the inspect

Comment: your problem here is that your server side not rendering the title tag

Comment: Yes exactly its like I didn't install angular universal at all