# In Angular is "view page source" ( ctrl + U ) necessary for SEO? Or is normal Angular build efficient?

Tags: angular, angularjs, seo, angular-routing, angular-universal

Problem:

We are using **Angular Universal for SEO** purpose where we can see content of our website by pressing **ctrl + U**.

Content of our main pages is visible but not internal pages.

We are using prerendered pages for deployment.

I need a answer which can prove

Case A : Normal angular build works properly for SEO and there is no need for Angular Universal prerendering.

Case B : Content and Meta Tags should be visible for SEO. No matter what technology we use.

Case C : Any other solution.

Here are the link provided by my SEO team which is having 10 + years of experience.

https://www.view-page-source.com/

https://backlinked.com/en/source-code/

Here is the proper explanation I found on Stacks Overflow

[Meta Title doesn't appear in view page source but its does in inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75260157/meta-title-doesnt-appear-in-view-page-source-but-its-does-in-inspect)